# Cyclic subgroups of same order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

If $G$ is a finite group  and $H$ and $K$ are two cyclic subgroups of same order  in G . Then  intersection of $H$ and $K$ is $\{e\}$ or $H=K$ .  Is it true? If yes then why  ?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the direct product of a group of order 2 and two groups of order 3. It has several cyclic subgroups of order six and one element of order 2, which is contained in all of them.